# ValueError at /indexsendjepp :I/O operation on closed file

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, file, zip

I want to upload zip file in 'F:comic\picture\jepp'. I use this code:

```
def sendjepp(request):
    docuPath ='F:comic\picture\jepp'
    temp = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
    f = zipfile.ZipFile(temp, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    for dirpath,dirnames,filenames in os.walk(docuPath):
          for filename in filenames:
              f.write(os.path.join(dirpath,filename))
    # f.close()
    wrapper = FileWrapper(temp)
    response = HttpResponse(wrapper, content_type='application/zip')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=test.zip'
    response['Content-Length'] = temp.tell()
    temp.seek(0)
    return response
```

I am getting this error:

[image]

Comment: try removing f.close()

Comment: had try delete f.close(), the outcome is same.

Comment: for sure f.close() with cause an error to be thrown. so if you remove that line where is the error being thrown?

Comment: That a problem. I don't know, so I hope find the reason. I realy have try to delete the f.close().

Comment: I just now edit the problem and update the outcome picture

Comment: if it helps, this is the culprit line- response = HttpResponse(wrapper, content_type='application/zip'). I removed this and things work fine.
print response gives: {'Content-Length': 86062, 'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=test.zip'}

Comment: Try to replace `temp.tell()` with `f.tell()`

Comment: Actually, what you really want to achieve? Uploading file must be much shorter :)

Comment: Anyway,thank you for your answer. if remove the -response = HttpResponse(wrapper, content_type='application/zip')-,outcome will be response is not define. what method should I use to transfer zipfiles? I found it on the Internet, obviously it's wrong, and no one knows why.
there are 10 files,each one is 100~200kb.

Answer (score 0):

Answering as I came across this issue and this was the only question I found.

You need to use `StreamingHttpResponse` ([docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#streaminghttpresponse-objects)) instead of `HttpResponse`.